# How can I return 401 for some URL when using spring security oAuth2 login

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to secure my application with Spring Security oAuth2. Is there a way to return 401 for some URL while other pages go to the login page if a user is not logged in.

For example, return login form for /ui/*, and return 401 for /api/*

I tried to use two `SecurityWebFilterChain`, but didn't success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure Spring Security to use a custom `AuthenticationEntryPoint`, something like:

```java
http
    // ... your configuration
    .exceptionHandling((ex) -> ex
        .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"), new AntPathRequestMatcher("/ui/**"))
        .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED), new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**"))
    );
```

This way Spring Security will pick up the `AuthenticationEntryPoint` based on the `RequestMatcher#matches` method

Comment: Thanks. My version of spring security has some different, and the codes are something like following:

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you were using the reactive bits. Anyway, I'm glad you were able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

My spring security version is something different, and the codes are something like following:

```java
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new DelegatingServerAuthenticationEntryPoint(
                new DelegatingServerAuthenticationEntryPoint.DelegateEntry(
                        ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers("/ui/**"),
                        new RedirectServerAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login")
                ),
                new DelegatingServerAuthenticationEntryPoint.DelegateEntry(
                        ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers("/api/**"),
                        new HttpStatusServerEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
                ))
        );
```